# D3js setting fill to none programmatically impacts onClick Event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

can someone explain to me what's wrong with the following method to manipulate path colors on different conditions?

```
    <button ID="btnTopo" onclick="fillTopo()"> FillTopo</button>

                var isTopo;
                function fillTopo() {

                            svgContainer.selectAll("path")
                                .filter(function (d) {
                                    if (d.properties.PE_Nr == 7000) { 
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                })
                                .attr("fill", isTopo ? "none" : "#FF6600");

                            svgContainer.selectAll("path")
                                .filter(function (d) {
                                    if (d.properties.PE_Nr == 7200) { 
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                })
                                .attr("fill", isTopo ? "none" : "#FFFF00");

                            svgContainer.selectAll("path")
                                .filter(function (d) {
                                    if (d.properties.PE_Nr == 6600) {
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                })
                                .attr("fill", isTopo ? "none" : "#F20000");

        .
        .
        .
isTopo = !isTopo;
        + 30
```

In the beginning, all my paths have fill: none and an onClickEvent which fires as I expect.

OnButtonClick I execute the fillTopo function. On the first click, everything works fine, my path OnClick-Event fires but on the second Click on the button, which changes fill to none again
my path onClick event stops firing.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you log the value of isTopo inside fillTopo function and see if the value is same or different in case of the first and the successive clicks. May be isTopo value is getting modified somewhere in your code.

Comment: I did add console.log at the beginning of my function and it's false (or undefined) and at the end it's true. On the second Click it's first true and then false. Seems that's everything is right. What I noticed is, that if I select a path, it gets fill:blue and then when I change the fill attribute to none on my button click the fill: blue remains and on that path my onMouseClick event fires.

Comment: Try removing all the existing paths from the svg in the beginning of the function and see if it works. Try this svgContainer.selectAll("path").remove();

Comment: My colleague found the problem, its because of fill:none. When I click on the boundary line my path onClick event fires. So now, when I "remove" my colors I just fill my paths with white. My mistake was to think that all my path had fill:none at the beginning but that's not true sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the [pointer-events property](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) so that your unfilled shapes still react to mouse clicks. It sounds like

```
 pointer-events: visible;
```

is probably what you want here.